# Deploying Symfony 3 application with Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony

I create a PHP environment with beanstalk using the console with "eb init" and "eb create". The thing is it fails because when it installs the dependencies with "composer install" automatically, it requires the database, but it's not attached yet. The error is:

> Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh
>   failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console
>   or EB CLI.

And eb-activity.log says that failed because it couldn't connect to the database.

I use this instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html to join the RDS database, but it does not work because the application deployment fails, so it does not add the security group to the environment.

If I create a small PHP app with a single file index.php, I can join the RDS database, but if I deploy my real app it returns an error because "I'm using different versions of the app".

It works if I create a database linked with the environment, bus this is not good practice for production.

How could I create an environment with my app and link the RDS database?

Comment: I ended up using Docker for building dev and prod environments, either you use AWS or not I recommend it